# State equations of Colpitts oscillator

Tags: oscillator, state-space

I am struggling with the simple oscillator on the picture below.

[image]

My aim is to obtain system of ODEs or DAE at most for numerical simulation in Matlab. But few issues occured with basic circuit theory.

For a nonlinear current \$i_d\$ I suppose piecewise defined function
\begin{equation*}
i_{\mathrm{n}} = 
    \begin{cases}
        0\quad \text{for } u_{\mathrm{gs}} - V_{\mathrm{T}}\leq 0\\
        \beta(u_{\mathrm{gs}} - V_{\mathrm{T}})^{n_2}(1 + \lambda u_{\mathrm{ds}})\mathrm{tanh}\,(\alpha u_{\mathrm{ds}}) \quad \text{for } u_{\mathrm{gs}} - V_{\mathrm{T}}> 0
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
for some given FET parameters \$\alpha\$, \$\beta\$, \$\lambda\$, pinchoff voltage \$V_{\mathrm{T}}\$ (it is VA approxiamtion used in Sussmann-Fort's MESFET model).

For the linear part I worked out these equations so far:

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}i_{L}}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{1}{L}(u_{\mathrm{ds}} - u_{\mathrm{gs}})\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}u_{C_d}}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{i_{C_d}}{C_{d}}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}u_{C_g}}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{i_{C_g}}{C_{g}}\\
\end{align}

Using KCL I obtain \$i_{R_{\mathrm{d}}} = i_L + i_{C_d} + i_{\mathrm{n}} + i_{R_1}\$. But how do I obtain \$i_{R_1}\$ and \$i_{C_d}\$ at the same time? Both branches with loads \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$ are giving me headache.

Second problem is that blocking capacitor \$C_\mathrm{b}\$. How we can tackle with floating capacitor while using ODE formalism?

**Note:** Somebody here suggested me MNA aproach which is not bad after all, but due to the lack of examples on use of inductor stamp with \$sL\$ rather than \$1/sL\$ (which would produce integrodifferential equation), I would like to ask for by hand solution.

**Edit:**
I managed to achieve these equations according to [this](https://depositonce.tu-berlin.de/bitstream/11303/1858/1/Dokument_18.pdf) thesis on MNA (pages 59-62). But it uses somewhat cumbersome notation so I am not really sure about the red current source if I understood it well. Can anyone check if it is legit to use my nonlinear current use on RHS like this? Sorry for the snippets, I was typsetting it for myself in overleaf.
[image]
[image]

It is clear after performing these opeartions we can obtain equations involving only derivatives of node voltages and inductor current. Currents through voltage sources are given without derivatives. But also I get \$u_R\$s which confuses me too.

Comment: Why not simulate this system in a dedicated electronics simulator like spice or its derivatives? That will save a lot of hassle.

Comment: If you want to derive the equations manually, I suggest you  have a look at Bondgraph theory. These can help you to discover if you have 6 independent states in your system, or if there are algebraic loops in your system requiring solvers that can handle these.
Bondgraphs provide a systematic method to determine the various equations.

Comment: Thank you, bondgraph theory looks like a good alternative